# Why do I receive a incorrect syntax error while creating a table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I am trying to create a table with the header which was read from a CSV file:

```
myConnection = new SqlConnection(cString);
myConnection.Open();

var lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);
List<string> readHeader = lines.ElementAt(0).Split(',').ToList();
string tab = "a123CSV";
readHeader.ToArray();
string exists = null;
try
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sysobjects where name = '" + tab + "'", myConnection);
   exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
catch (Exception ce)
{
   exists = null;
}

if (exists == null)
{
   int p;
   for (p = 0; p <= readHeader.Count; p++)
   {
      if (exists == null)
      {
         SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + tab + "' ([" + readHeader[p] + "] varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
         createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
         exists = tab;
      }
      else
      {
         SqlCommand addcolumn = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE '" + tab + "' ADD [" + readHeader[p] + "] varchar(MAX)", myConnection);
         addcolumn.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
}
```

The header in the CSV file is this:

> "NPI","Entity Type Code","Replacement NPI","Employer Identification
>   Number (EIN)","Provider Organization Name (Legal Business
>   Name)","Provider Last Name (Legal Name)","Provider First
>   Name","Provider Middle Name","Provider Name Prefix Text"

Whenever I run my application I keep getting this error on this line:

```
...
if (exists == null)
{
SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + tab + "' ([" + readHeader[p].Replace("\"", "") + "] varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near `a123CSV`
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: First thing to fix: stop embedding values directly into your SQL. Use parameterized SQL. That may well be enough to make *other* errors more obvious... while also fixing SQL Injection Attack vulnerabilities.

Comment: I will be using parameter once I have the query working :) Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @JonSkeet Is a parameterized query *capable* of dynamically specifying the name of a table to be created?  I didn't think that was a valid task they could perform.

Comment: @Servy: Not that bit, no - but there's code to be fixed *other* than the table name.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: You should get in the habit of using parameterized queries right from the start. It's like saying "I won't bother formatting my code or using meaningful variable names until I've finished."

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I will start doing it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the table name with `[` and `]` instead of single quotes, i.e.:

```
"CREATE TABLE [" + tab + "] ([" + readHeader[p].Replace("\"", "") + "] varchar(MAX))"
```

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't looking at it that way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are enclosing TABLE_NAME inside single quotes. Use this,

```
SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + tab + " ([" + readHeader[p].Replace("\"", "") + "] varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
```

Comment: I will replace the single quote with `[]` just incase the table name which will be gives by the user has a space to it.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Until a user enters a table name of `]; drop table sysobjects; -- `

Comment: I am using filter in the textbox to ensure only letters and numbers are allowed and only letter as the first character. :)